# Access event handler inside component

Tags: event-handling, components, svelte

I have a custom button component that accepts on:click event handler. Currently it looks like this:

```
<!-- Button.svelte -->
<button on:click>
  <slot />
</button>
```

And I use it like this

```
<Button on:click={doStuff}>click me</Button>
```

I want to access `doStuff` handler inside `Button` component to wrap it with another function. How can I do that?

I know that I can add a custom `onClick` prop, but this is ugly.

Answer (score 2):

You can call a function inside Button component than dispatch click event, so that will work as wrapper method.

Something like this

```
/* Button.svelte */

const handleClick = () => {
  // your wrapper method or logic here
  dispatch('click'); // this is basically doStuff()
}

<button on:click={handleClick}>
  <slot />
</button>
```

Comment: Wow, thank you, that is a great answer! But what if I want to access the function itself? Is it possible? I want to show a spinner on a button if the handler is async. I would like to access the promise and use it in `{#await}` block.

Comment: And, by the way, what target would that click event have?